# Keras: Altered ImageDataGenerator gives error "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument"

Tags: tensorflow, keras, data-augmentation, image-preprocessing

I am using `keras=2.3.1` and I wanted to use my own version of zca_whitening. For that, I made changes directly into the `ImageDataGenerator` class in the keras file `/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/image_data_generator.py`. The file, including my changes is this [one](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cyfe17EDr598pFjfRR1_FVlRZ6ZGCDYv). My neural network file `nn_script.py` that uses this altered `image_data_generator.py` can be seen [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RjXwzSDP7XGjyKOzcA1SRkDzrDEEy9Au/view?usp=sharing). There are no problems, as long as `nn_script.py` uses the default keras augmentaions like:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=30,
    shear_range=0.2,
    samplewise_center=True, samplewise_std_normalization=True)
```

But if I decide to switch on my custom version of zca_whitening called `zca_whitening_fast` in this way

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=30,
    shear_range=0.2,
    samplewise_center=True, samplewise_std_normalization=True,
    zca_whitening_fast=True)
```

I get the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nn_script.py", line 55
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'zca_whitening_fast'
```

You can reproduce my error message by substituting your `image_data_generator.py` file with the one I posted above and trying to create a generator with the option `zca_whitening_fast=True`.

First I thought the problem is, that I have forgotten to include `zca_whitening_fast` in `def __init__()` in the file `image_data_generator.py`, but it is there, as you can check. I also tried deleting the `__pycache__` folder, because I thought, that some older files are getting executed in this folder, but the same error appeared. Now I wonder if the error message comes from an `__init__()` that is in a different file, not in `image_data_generator.py`. I think the solution is something obvious, I probably need to make a change in another file in the keras preprocessing folder, but I don't know which. I don't think the problem is because my keras version is old and because of compatibility reasons with my graphic card I can't upgrade keras.

Any ideas why I get this error message? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You modified the files in the `keras_preprocessing` package, but you are probably importing `keras.preprocessing`, which is a different package. This is fine, `keras.preprocessing` just forwards all calls to `keras_preprocessing`.

So what you need to do is to also make your modifications to the `keras/preprocessing/image.py` files inside the `keras` package, as shown [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py#L241).

Comment: Thanks! I made the changes in `keras/preprocessing/image.py`, but the same error appears :( Do I need to update something? And is there a way to trace from what file comes this error message `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'zca_whitening_fast'`?