# Make python show file origin of error message

Tags: python, keras, error-handling, error-messaging

**General python question: Is there a way to get an error message to show the file location of the `__init__()` causing the error?**

My concrete problem: I am running a file `nn_script.py` containing keras commands that gives me the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nn_script.py", line 55
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'zca_whitening_fast'
```

[My file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RjXwzSDP7XGjyKOzcA1SRkDzrDEEy9Au/view) `nn_script.py` doesn't contain any `__init__()`, but it uses imports from other files, like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras import backend #from keras import backend
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

More importantly, I made changes to the default keras files `/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/image_data_generator.py` and `/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py`, where I included the variable `zca_whitening_fast`, see my inclusions [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cyfe17EDr598pFjfRR1_FVlRZ6ZGCDYv/view) and [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cyfe17EDr598pFjfRR1_FVlRZ6ZGCDYv/view?usp=sharing). Despite the inclusion, I still get the error message `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'zca_whitening_fast'` and I think there might be a 3rd file I need to change.

So I ask myself now the question at the very top of this post. Thanks!

*If you are interested in my code changes leading the to the problem see my other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60116894/keras-altered-imagedatagenerator-gives-error-init-got-an-unexpected-keyw), althoguh this is not necessary for answering this question*

Comment: Just a hunch but I guess you should check the imports. Maybe there's a class named `zca_whitening_fast` somewhere in Keras.

Comment: @Jarmos I created `zca_whitening_fast` myself and wanted to include it into the keras class `ImageDataGenerator`, but then from different places comes the error message `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'zca_whitening_fast'`, so I want to find the exact file locations where the errors occur, so that I can fix them. Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: A few more questions, the `../keras_preprocessing/image/image_data_generator.py` is something that you created? Could you edit the description and share the file structure too?

Comment: @Jarmos I didn't create the file, it is a default keras file, I only included in this file my own variable `zca_whitening_fast` with the calculation of this variable. I put more info in my initial post. Thanks!